# How to get image URL and metrics by ID from Gutenberg frontend

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

How can I query the URL, height, width and alt text of an image by its media id using JavaScript?

There's a way to do so by using the PHP function `wp_get_attachment_metadata`.

Is there a JavaScript function I can call in frontend to get the image metadata (for both newly uploaded media and previously uploaded media)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WordPress [REST API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/) can be used to retrieve the media details with JavaScript. There is a media endpoint which is very useful if you have the ID:

```
https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/media/<id>
```

The JSON returned contains all the information about the media, including:

```
{
    "alt_text": "Lorem ipsum...", 
    "source_url": "http://...",
    "media_details": {
        "height": 400, 
        "width": 600
     }
    ...
}
```

Reference: [REST API Handbook / Reference / Media](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/media/#definition-example-request)